# Efficient Lemmatizer that avoids dictionary lookup

Tags: java, relevance, text-analysis, lemmatization

I want to convert string like 'eat' to 'eating', 'eats'. I searched and found the lemmatization as the solution, but all the lemmatizer tools that I have come across uses wordlist or dictionary-lookup. Is there any lemmatizer which avoids dictionary lookup and gives high efficiency, may be a lemmatizer that is based on rules. Yes and I am not looking for "stemmer".

Answer (score 1):

You can try [LRBL](http://www.ccl.kuleuven.be/~richard/lemmatizer/): a rule-based lemmatizer

It uses the concept of recursive acronyms.